# Mask time series xarray dataset based on the other overlapping dataset?

Tags: python, xarray

I have `Dataset1` that have time series of vegetation moisture values (`fmc_mean`) and `Dataset2` that have vegetation cover types `LC_Type1` (grass - 1, shrub - 2, forest -3) that overlaps with `Dataset1`.

```
Dataset1
  <xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (time: 92, x: 138, y: 192)
Coordinates:
  * x             (x) float64 1.508e+06 1.509e+06 ... 1.576e+06 1.577e+06
  * y             (y) float64 -3.936e+06 -3.936e+06 ... -4.031e+06 -4.031e+06
  * time          (time) datetime64[ns] 2014-01-01 2014-01-05 ... 2014-12-31
    spatial_ref   int32 0
Data variables:
    fmc_mean      (time, y, x) float32 nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
    fmc_stdv      (time, y, x) float32 nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
    quality_mask  (time, y, x) float32 nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
    


   Dataset2
   xarray.Dataset
Dimensions: band:1 x:123 y:173
Coordinates:
y    (y)    float64    -3.941e+06 ... -4.027e+06
x    (x)    float64    1.513e+06 1.513e+06 ... 1.574e+06
band (band) int32      1
spatial_ref ()         int32   0
Data variables: 
LC_Type1   (band, y, x)   float64   nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
```

I want to mask `Dataset1` based on the `Dataset2`, so only forest cover (`LC_Type1==3`) `fmc_mean` will be assigned to the new dataset `Dataset_forest` with following code:

```
Dataset_forest = Dataset1.where(Datset2.LC_Type1==3) # is this code correct?
```

But, it results empty dataset.

```
Dataset_forest
xarray.Dataset
Dimensions: band:1 time:92 x:0 y:0
Coordinates:
x    (x)    float64
y    (y)    float64
time (time) datetime64[ns] 2014-01-01 ... 2014-12-31
spatial_ref ()     int32 0
band        (band) int32 1
Data variables:
fmc_mean     (time, y, x, band) float32
fmc_stdv     (time, y, x, band) float32
quality_mask (time, y, x, band) float32
```

I re-projected coordinates to make the Datasets have the same coordinate system and they seem to overlap.
[image]
I am quite new to Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coordinates have to match exactly for `where` to work. Since your x and y values are slightly different no matches can be found.

To fix this you can use `interp()` to interpolate one of the rasters to the same coordinate grid of the other raster:

```
time, x, y = Dataset1.indexes.values()
ds2_interp = Dataset2.interp(x=x, y=y, method="nearest")
```

This should work, I haven't tested it myself though. You might also have to add the time dimension for it to work.

Comment: Great, thank you very much @JonasV. I was stuck for 2 days trying to solve this. Really appreciate your help!